# How to pass data from function to stateful?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i'm use mqtt on flutter.
I want to display the data received from the topic (payload and topic name) in the StatefulWidget widget.

```
      client.updates!.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage>> c) {
final MqttPublishMessage message;
message = c[0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;
final payload =
    MqttPublishPayload.bytesToStringAsString(message.payload.message);
print('Received message:$payload from topic: ${c[0].topic}>');});
```

how to send data to setState of statefulwidgets?

Answer (score 0):

```
 setState(() {
      _myValue = newValue;
    });
```

Comment: thanks. I want to send data from the out of class function to class setState.

Comment: If it is in another class, create a getter: `getValue() { return value;}`, then call this in your other file.